# Facing issue in building nested URL in Django 1.11

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a Hierarchy where in homepage user has option to select Location in their Homepage and then once they select the location they get Respective Managers from that location and next once they select the managers they get respective associate.

Diagram -> (Homepage) all locations -on select specific location- > Managers -  on select specific Manager- > List of associate (aligned to the manager )

Url Patterns:

```
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<hierarchy_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.managerview, name='managerview'),
    url(r'(?P<associate_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.associatelist, name='associatelist'),

]
```

Views:

```
def index(request):
    all_sites = Hierarchy.objects.all()
    return render(request, "adash/index.html", {'all_sites': all_sites})


def managerview(request, hierarchy_id):
    all_managers = Hierarchy.objects.get(pk=hierarchy_id)
    return render(request, "adash/manager.html", {'all_managers': all_managers})


def associatelist(request, associate_id):
    all_logins = Hierarchy.objects.get(pk=associate_id)
    return render(request, "adash/associatelist.html", {'all_logins': all_logins})
```

### Manager Html

```
<a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><h5 class = "text-monospace">{{ all_managers.direct_manager }}</h5></a>
```

### Associate Html

```
<a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><h5 class = "text-monospace">{{ all_logins.login }}</h5></a>
```

currently am able to click on location and direct it to respective managers associated with that site but how to proceed to next step i.e click on manager and show list of associate.

Below is my model:

```
class Hierarchy(models.Model):
    site = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    direct_manager = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    login = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `direct_manager` field needs to be a relationship, not a text field. This is a recursive relationship, where an instance of Hierarchy points to another instance which is its manager. So:

```
direct_manager = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='direct_reports')
```

Now, given an instance of Hierarchy which is a manager, you can get all associates via the reverse relation:

```
associates = my_manager.direct_reports.all()
```